# Adding ChildViewController's view to a root ViewController

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add a child viewcontroller to a root view controller

in the interface builder i put a container which looks like this :

[image: generic layout]

i wanted to add default margins of 20 to the container in relation to its superview

however, the views inside the childviewcontroller seem to slide out of the container's bounds

why ?

```
self.lvc = (LoginViewController *) [self.storyboard loginViewController];
    [self addChildViewController:self.lvc];
    self.fullFrameContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.fullFrameContainer addSubview:self.lvc.view];
    [self.lvc didMoveToParrentViewController:self];


  result :
```

[image]

Comment: have you added the child view controllers view as a subview of the main view?

Comment: Just curious, what is this suppose to do: [self.storyboard loginViewController]? Should not it be instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:?

Comment: it is, self.storyboard ... is a category that does just that

Comment: OK. Well adding the child in code really breaks things. If you add the child with embed segue, it will work. Try that.

Comment: I think for adding in code, you are not setting the childVC frame, and therefore it takes default full screen frame and adds it to bounds 0,0 of the container, which is at 20,20. This way your labels and buttons overlaps its superview. You can test it if you clip the bounds of the container.

Comment: Updated the answer with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you seeing, but you should add second ViewController next to your root ViewController, set embeded segue, and then set constraints for your containverView to be your chosen 20 pt and in the Child VC you should also set your contraints to be 0 in each direction (leading, trailing, top, bottom). You child VC in IB will also automatically resize so you have a visual feedback of the child VC frame.

[image]

**Edit:**

Update your lvc frame in code or in storyboard and it will work:

```
self.lvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childVC"];

NSLog(@"%.0f %.0f", self.lvc.view.frame.size.width, self.lvc.view.frame.size.height);

self.lvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 280.0, 508.0);
[self.lvc.view layoutSubviews];

[self addChildViewController:self.lvc];
self.fullFrameContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.fullFrameContainer addSubview:self.lvc.view];
```

Comment: i tried adding the constraints on both child and container like you said, but that was why i posted this question. this suggestion did not work :(

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your constraints, how are they set?

Comment: Added sample storyboard setup with constraints.

Comment: i did as you wrote, and see my result above ?

Answer (score 1):

in viewWillAppear i added this line

```
self.lvc.view.frame = self.fullFrameContainer.bounds;
```

and it fixed the floating out of frame problems